# Retrieve arguments of a x64 masm assembly procedure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, 64-bit, masm

I have a function with the signature :

```
extern "C" int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
```

which is in fact written in assembly.

With ml(32 bits), using standard calling convention you can pretty much write

```
.code
foo PROC a: DWORD, b: DWORD ,c: DWORD, d: DWORD, e: DWORD

     mov eax, d
     mov ebx, e
```

and start using those labels to access your arguments

With ml64 (64 bits) the fastcall is the only convention available. I have no trouble accessing the first arguments stored in the registers, but issues to access the ones in the stack (`e` in this example): I tried

```
.code
foo PROC a: DWORD, b: DWORD ,c: DWORD, d: DWORD, e: DWORD
```

and

```
.code
foo PROC  e: DWORD
```

but the value in `e` is garbage.

***I found that if I use the stack address directly I find the value.***

```
.code
foo PROC  e: DWORD

     mov eax, r9                  ; d
     mov ebx, DWORD PTR[rbp + 48] ; e
```

**Is there another way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation explains everything...  In Windows, the first four integer parameters are passed in registers `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, `R9` and floating point in `XMM0`, `XMM1`, `XMM2`, `XMM3`, anything more than four parameters are passed on the stack above the shadow space.  For Unix type OS's it is a bit different.

So, your example is correct - `mov ebx, DWORD PTR[rbp + 48] ; e`

Shadow space = 32 + saved rbp = 40 + 5th parameter = 48

Answer (score 0):

given

```
extern "C" int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
```

I found out that visual studio 2010 doesn't save the base pointer `RBP` if

```
.code
foo PROC
```

but save the base pointer if

```
.code
foo PROC  e: DWORD
```

Later versions (vs2015) don't allow the second code.

[There is an optional optimization in x64 systems where `RBP` is not used](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64) (found out the hard way). It says :

> The conventional use of %rbp as a frame pointer for the stack frame
>   may be avoided by using %rsp (the stack pointer) to index into the
>   stack frame. This technique saves two instructions in the prologue and
>   epilogue and makes one additional general-purpose register (%rbp)
>   available.

So it is possible that either `foo PROC  e: DWORD` doesnt compile (vs2015), or `foo PROC` crashes because RBP is null.

The correct way to retrieve stack arguments is to use the `RSP` stack pointer given that

```
RBP = RSP + 8 * num_saved_reg
```

Where `num_saved_reg` is the number of registers specified in the PROC directive. So when rbp is not saved (otherwise add 8)

```
PROC -> DWORD PTR[rsp + 40]
PROC use RDI -> DWORD PTR[rsp + 40 + 8]
PROC use RDI RSI RBX -> DWORD PTR[rsp + 40 + 24]
```

Comment: The problem with your answer comes when you call into another function; this will clobber the stack pointer and you will get a stack exception. It *should* work if you never call into another function, but don't quote me on that, and it's safest just to save and restore the stack pointer.